# How can I get a longer automatic excerpt in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Currently, I include excerpts like this:

```
{{ post.excerpt | strip_html }}
```

But this seems to give only the first paragraph. But I would like to get a fixed number of words.

Or better: I would like to define a maximum number of characters and get so many words that

- the number of characters is less than the maximum
- one word more would be over the maximum number of characters

Is there a way to do this with Jekyll (1.3.1)?

edit: `<!-- more -->` is not an answer! I think excerpting should work automatically and my posts should only contain markup that is absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'm not quiet sure, but I think you have to amend the Jekyll engine itself. Check out their source code on github. See line 106ff https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/excerpt.rb

Comment: I hoped I could simply use something built-in. For WordPress, there are many plugins ([summy](http://wordpress.org/plugins/summy/), [advanced excerpt](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/), [search excerpt](http://scott.yang.id.au/code/search-excerpt/), ...). Maybe next weekend. When I write a plugin / adjust the `excerpt.rb`, I'll post it as an answer. (By the way: Hi Tobi :-) )

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The following gives a 75 words automatic excerpt:

```
{{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords:75 }}
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually `<!-- more -->` is the answer. At least, it works well now.

1. Add this line to your _config.yml:

   `excerpt_separator: "<!-- more -->"`
2. Then add this to each post in your site:

   `<!-- more -->`

Hope it will help.